# Using md-select and md-autocomplete together

Tags: angular-material

I'm trying to allow the users of my app to choose a single item in a big select (~2500 possibilities). So, as I already implemented md-chips with md-autocomplete in another app, I thought that all I had to do was to the same with a md-select. To my surprise, I didn't find a way to do that.

So basically I have 3 choices :

- use md-chips but I can't limit them to one chip, I can show an error if two or more are chosen, but that's a rather weird UX to let the user choose two things and then alert them they can't.
- use md-select, but from what I gathered, I can't use md-autocomplete, so choosing between 2500 objects is tedious
- use md-autocomplete, but (not sure :) there's no ng-model, and worst my user can write about anything while I just want them to select one item

I'm sure I missed something in the docs, I just can't find a way to allow my users to select one and only one item with autocomplete.

Anyone ?

Comment: You can use md -max-chips to limit the chips.

Comment: from what I tried, (md-max-chips="1") it only puts an error on the md-chips if the user selects more than one item, you can still select a second item, that's when I thought to myself that a select would more appropriate, because it has a mode where you can only choose one item. Unfortunately, it doesn't have an autocomplete possbility, which I found rather odd.

Comment: I don't get your point. You mean that if user select more than one item, they can add more chips?

Comment: The point is that with md-max-chips="1", the user can actually choose 2 or more items, it's just that you'll be able to tell him to remove every item but one with an error message. wouldn't you find odd, if a form field titled "select a place" allowed you to select more than a place, and then yelled at you because you did ? I hope it's clearer.